# How do I add an image to a URL item in a SharePoint document library?

Tags: image, url, sharepoint

I am building a document library in sharepoint that contains files and URLs.  The files all have an image that acts as a preview to the document.  However, all the URLs all have the same image.

[image: a screenshot of a sharepoint document library showing the default URL image]

How can I add unique images, or just something different than the default image, to the URL items in the library?

Answer (score 0):

In the Sharepoint document, different icons will be displayed according to the type of each file, which is to simply distinguish the type of file, not a thumbnail. And cannot be changed to a different icon. This is by design.